# Formal way of thanking someone for pointing out a mistake

Tags: expressions, colloquial-language

When a colleague points out a mistake you made, is it too formal to respond: "Thanks for alerting me to this mistake." What would be an alternative to "Thanks, my bad!"

Answer (score 1):

*alerting* is a good choice when you're trying not to sound too formal or too informal.

And *thanks* is also informal.

*My bad* means "sorry, that was *my* fault". Only if your mistake has harmed others ("harm" very broadly construed) would you use that phrase. For example, when a football player makes an error, such as by passing the ball out of reach of a teammate who might have scored had the pass been accurate, the player might say "my bad".  It's a curt acknowledgement that it was you who goofed, that *it was not the other person's fault*.

Comment: Thank you! So "thanks for alerting me to this mistake." would be the right kind of in-between?

Comment: Yes, it's an informal but not too informal statement.  More formal would be *Thank you for bringing this error to my attention.*

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by @Tᴚoɯɐuo is correct.

An alternative would be to identify what the other person's action has done **for** you, rather than acknowledging your mistake. You could say:

> Thank you. That is very helpful.

Note how that acts as an approval for the person to identify similar mistakes is the future. You may want that with, for example, a peer at work. People are reluctant to point out others mistakes too often. They don't want to appear to be nagging. This would convey a message you are happy to be mentored.